# How can I make text influence an image?

Tags: html, css

I have an image with a piece of text above it. The image is set to scale in and turn to color when hovered over, and the text is a link to a site. How can I make the text and image one "element", so that when I hover over the text the image expands and turns to color independently of having to hover over the image itself?

There may not be a solution to this, but because the only other option I can think of is making the picture and text one image is a rather coarse one, I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Relevant Code:

```css
img.color_flip {
  filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale);
  /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  filter: gray;
  /* IE5+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  /* Webkit Nightlies & Chrome Canary */
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
img.color_flip:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.02);
}
* {
  padding: 40;
  margin: 40;
}
#over {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.Centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.imgWrap {
  position: relative;
}
.imgDescription {
  position: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #afafaf;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="over">
  <div class="imgWrap">
    <div>
      <a href="http://prxnt.org/faces.html">
        <span class="imgDescription" position="bottom" style="margin-top:10px">Shop summer tees
         </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <img class="color_flip" class="Centered" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/7ab99a5.jpg" width="707" style="margin-top:10px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So I don't know how to recreat what you are looking for, but I did make this jsfiddle:

[text and image hover](https://jsfiddle.net/jaspercreel/2zhrdnLv/1/)

Basically I used:

```
.image-box p:hover ~ img {
  width:200px;
}
```

to select the img once the paragraph was hovered over. It applies an effect to the image independent of hovering over the image. It's a little rough but the effect is there. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, this is perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your description was all over the place...I couldn't follow. So I made one div and a crapload of CSS:

- Use `background: url(https://domain.com/path/to/img.png) no-repeat;` and `background-size: contain` to use an image as a background and maintain aspect-ratio (i.e. stretched as far to the edges as possible without distorting the image.)
- Use `transition: color .2s ease-out, font-size 1s ease-in;` to animate text's color fade-in and growing font.
- On `:hover` you simply assign the color and font-size as you want it to end up as. When not hovered on the text color is transparent and only 8px. When it's hovered on the animation (`transition`) kicks in and the text is navy color and a 48px font-size.

### SNIPPET

```css
.img {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  text-align: center;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-family: 'Palatino Light';
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-out, font-size 1s ease-in;
  transition: color .2s ease-out, font-size 1s ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.img:hover {
  color: navy;
  font-size: 48px;
  padding-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">.::Lenna::.</div>
```